# XSLT inserting a TXT file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT  to transform a XML file in to a HTML file.

I would like to insert a plain text file in to the HTML as part of the transform.

Is this possible?

Comment: which XSLT processor are you using? That would help us know whether to advise XSLT 2.0, or an extension function, or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the solution that I ended up using was somewhat simpler than those suggested above. I used the following :

```
<xsl:variable name="input-text" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text('../Input/pipehat.txt', 'iso-8859-1')"/>
```

to get the text into a variable then just output the variable in the appropriate place.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$input-text"/>
```

Comment: Actually, that was suggestion number 2. :)

Comment: The value can be read directly without creating any variable: `<xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('../Input/pipehat.txt', 'iso-8859-1')"/>`

Answer (score 8):

You have a few options:

1. If you can surround the plain text in `<text></text>` tags, you may import it with the [`document()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function. This works in XSLT1.0, and does not require another programming language.
2. If you cannot modify the source file, but you do have XSLT2.0, then you may do it using [`unparsed-text()`](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/09/xslt.html).
3. If you do not have XSLT2.0, but you are using Java, then you may be able to [invoke a Java function](http://www.edankert.com/transforms/xslt.invoke-java.html). Microsoft platforms will probably offer similar functionality.

Comment: +1, good answer. Note to reader, #1 means surround the plain text with `<text></text>` *in the text file itself*, not in the XSLT template.

Comment: @LarsH: So, the options are: 1) Make your text resource an XML resource; 2) Use XSLT 2.0; 3) Use (or develop) an extension function.- Neither 1 or 3 are well defined in answer...

Comment: @Alejandro: The first one is actually quite well defined, I think. "Surround the plain text in tags". The last depends a lot on the platform you are using, example given for Java. If BENBUN Coder had given a little more info on the environment this has to run in, a clear example could be given. However, it's still a pointer in the right direction, you should be able to figure it out from there. SO is not a _'can you code this for me'_ site, is it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the options Matthijs Bierman mentioned, you can also pass the contents of the text file into the transform as an argument, if the environment you're working with supports this.

For instance, in .NET, a program that performs a transform can read a file into a string variable, add it as a parameter to an `XsltArgumentList` object, and pass this object to the `XslCompiledTransform`'s `Transform` method.